# Is CircuitBuildTimeout saved through sessions?

Tags: configuration, circuit, client

In the [Tor manpage](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) I read about `CircuitBuildTimeout`. It is set to a default value of 60 seconds. However usually also `LearnCircuitBuildTimeout` is set. This enables adaptive learning of those timeouts. Does this setting only affect the current Tor session or is it saved over various sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/path-spec.txt) (see section 2.4.2.) `CircuitBuildTimeout` is used across sessions.

> **Timeouts are stored on disk** in a histogram of 50ms bin width, the same width used to calculate the Xm value above. This histogram must be shuffled after **being read from disk**, to preserve a proper expiration of old values after restart.

The specification includes the following, too:

> The Tor client should build test circuits at a rate of one per minute up until 100 circuits are built. This allows a **fresh Tor** to have a CircuitBuildTimeout **estimated within 1.5 hours** after install, upgrade, or network change (see below).

which wouldn't be included if an **already used Tor** would need the same amount of time.